# How to add term description to view?

Tags: views

I have a list of nodes (ubercart products) filtered by taxonomy term. How can I attach a term description to the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the tid used in the view in a preprocess hook, and use it to get the description and render it where you want.

Another solution would be to create an area handler that displays the description. This could then be used to render the term description in the header or footer section of the view.

To create an area handler you need to subclass `views_handler_area` and add your area handler to the term using `hook_views_data_alter`

```
hook_views_data_alter(&$data) {
  $data['taxonomy_term_data']['your_area_handler'] = array(
    'title' => t('Title'),
    'help' => t('Help text.'),
    'area' => array(
      'handler' => 'your_views_area_handler_class',
    ),
  );
}
```

The area handler doesn't need much more than a render function which acts as it's theming function, so it's not that tricky.